# Colouring sectioning titles

Tags: sectioning, color

What is a good way to colour section commands blue?  This is what I have done

```
\newcommand{\sec}[1]{\section{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{\subsection{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\subsubsec}[1]{\subsubsection{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
```

Perhaps the use of `\textcolor` is not appropriate because latex sectioning allows math environments.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Would like it for `article`, `report`, `book`, and `beamer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way consists in using the `titlesec` package – explicitly load the package and add to your preamble:

```
 \titleformat*{\section}{\color{blue}}
   
 \titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{blue}}
   
 \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\color{blue}}
```

Comment: So by using `\color`.